# Using the devExpress WinForms controls with Clarion NET

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, clarion

How seamless is the integration of devexpress winforms controls in Clarion NET? Does it work at all? Is it comfortable?

Answer (score 0):

Best think to do is to download the DevExpress controls and try it. (they will run as trial).